# Object does not get created on Virtual PC

Tags: vba, excel, vpc, virtualization

I have set up a virtual PC (XP SP3) for executing automation developed in VBA. This automation creates an object of few Dlls developed in C# and VB.Net. But when I execute the automation using this VPC machine; the required objects does not get created and automation fails. Please let me know what could be the reasons for the same and how to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue has been resolved. I required to run the windows update as some updated related to Office were not available on machine. Thanks.

Comment: You can checkmark your own answer to remove it from the 'underanswered' set of questions.